# Vector addition of lists

Tags: lisp, scheme

If I had a N lists each of length M, how could I write a nice clean function to return a single list of length M, where each element is the sum of the corresponding elements in the N lists?

(starting to learn lisp - go easy!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a job for the `map` and `apply` functions. Here is a way to do it, with an **EDIT** suggested by Nathan Sanders:

```
(define (add-lists . more)
  (apply map + more))
```

Comment: Apply takes multiple arguments, only the last is a list, so you could get away with `(apply map + more)`

Comment: Sorry - I was making some embarrassing mistakes. Thanks for your excellent answer!

Comment: @Nathan: Cool. I didn't know that applied to Scheme's `apply`; I do most of my Lisping in CL.

Answer (score 2):

For a more matlab like syntax:

```
(define (piecewise func)
  (lambda more
    (apply map func more)))
(define pw piecewise)

((pw +) '(1 2 3 4 5) '(6 7 8 9 0))
((pw -) '(1 2 3 4 5) '(6 7 8 9 0))
((pw *) '(1 2 3 4 5) '(6 7 8 9 0))
((pw /) '(1 2 3 4 5) '(6 7 8 9 0.1))
```

outputs:

```
(7 9 11 13 5)
(-5 -5 -5 -5 5)
(6 14 24 36 0)
(1/6 2/7 3/8 4/9 50.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just  this works in MIT scheme.

```
 (map + '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8 9))
;Value 28: (12 15 18)
```